# Problem when trying to implement a variable in a heatmap using highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, object, highcharts

I am currently trying to plot the values of a thermographic (AMG8833) inside a heatmap using highcharts module. As the values update in real time, these values are being sent through a nodemcu board and received in the html file. It is very strange as when I try to plot the value by itself using: (this part of the code repeats for each pixel of the camera)

```
setInterval(function () {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var pixel_0 = parseFloat(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("pixel_0").innerHTML = pixel_0;
        pixel_0.innerHTML = pixel_0;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/pixels[0]", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }, 1000 );
```

and

```
  <h3>"The value for pixel 0 is: " <span id="pixel_0"></span></h3>
```

It shows the value perfectly. The problem comes when I try to put this value inside the data for my heatmap:

```
$(function () {
    $('#Thermographic_camera').highcharts({

      chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 8,
        plotBorderColor: '#FFFFFF'
      },


      title: {
        text: 'Thermographic camera'
      },

      xAxis: {
        categories: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      },

      yAxis: {
        categories: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        title: null
      },

      colorAxis: {
        //min: 0,
        //minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        //maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8]

        stops: [
          [0, '#3060cf'],
          [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
          [0.9, '#c4463a']
        ],
        min: 20,
        max: 40
      },

      legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280

      },


      series: [{
        name: 'Value',
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, pixel_0],
          [0, 1, pixel_1],
          [0, 2, pixel_2],
          [0, 3, pixel_3],
          [0, 4, pixel_4],
          [0, 5, pixel_5],
          [0, 6, pixel_6],
          [0, 7, pixel_7],
          [1, 0, pixel_8],
          [1, 1, pixel_9],
          [1, 2, pixel_10],
          [1, 3, pixel_11],
          [1, 4, pixel_12],
          [1, 5, pixel_13],
          [1, 6, pixel_14],
          [1, 7, pixel_15],
          [2, 0, pixel_16],
          [2, 1, pixel_17],
          [2, 2, pixel_18],
          [2, 3, pixel_19],
          [2, 4, pixel_20],
          [2, 5, pixel_21],
          [2, 6, pixel_22],
          [2, 7, pixel_23],
          [3, 0, pixel_24],
          [3, 1, pixel_25],
          [3, 2, pixel_26],
          [3, 3, pixel_27],
          [3, 4, pixel_28],
          [3, 5, pixel_29],
          [3, 6, pixel_30],
          [3, 7, pixel_31],
          [4, 0, pixel_32],
          [4, 1, pixel_33],
          [4, 2, pixel_34],
          [4, 3, pixel_35],
          [4, 4, pixel_36],
          [4, 5, pixel_37],
          [4, 6, pixel_38],
          [4, 7, pixel_39],
          [5, 0, pixel_40],
          [5, 1, pixel_41],
          [5, 2, pixel_42],
          [5, 3, pixel_43],
          [5, 4, pixel_44],
          [5, 5, pixel_45],
          [5, 6, pixel_46],
          [5, 7, pixel_47],
          [6, 0, pixel_48],
          [6, 1, pixel_49],
          [6, 2, pixel_50],
          [6, 3, pixel_51],
          [6, 4, pixel_52],
          [6, 5, pixel_53],
          [6, 6, pixel_54],
          [6, 7, pixel_55],
          [7, 0, pixel_56],
          [7, 1, pixel_57],
          [7, 2, pixel_58],
          [7, 3, pixel_59],
          [7, 4, pixel_60],
          [7, 5, pixel_61],
          [7, 6, pixel_62],
          [7, 7, pixel_63],
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          color: '#000000'
        }
      }]

    });
  });
```

When I do so, I obtain the answer in the heatmap that the variable i am trying to put inside the heatmap is an [object HTMLSpanElement] and it does not put the actual value of the variables of each pixel.

Any clue on what could I be doing wrong?
Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Hi@Ramon, You probably missed to update series data after the data is recieved. You can for example use the `update` method for point. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s1kLnpc2/

Comment: Thank you very much!! What I actually did is use the command addPoint to introduce the values and that has worked out for me